# Razor page as custom error message in asp.net without redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, error-handling

I am trying to get a message page to display a custom message if the visitor browses to a page eg. nothere.cshtml or to a none existing folder eg. /folder/nothere/

I would like to keep the url visible and not do a redirect

I have tried the following in system.web

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/message.cshtml" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/message.cshtml" />
</customErrors>
```

And the following in system.webserver

```
<httpErrors>
<remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
<error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/message.cshtml" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

But I get a Server error in "/" application for a file and a standard 404 error message when browsing to a directory that do not exist.

I am able to make a custom error message using the normal responseRedirect but then the URL are not kept original

Anybody?